# How to get connection string in AppService?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Is it possible to get the connection string from an AppService? I want to use Dapper directly as below:

```
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection(_connString))
{
   //My code here
}
```

Can I get `_connString` from AppService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there's a Dapper integration of ABP.

install Dapper from Nuget
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Abp.Dapper

And read the doc https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Dapper-Integration

if you still want to get a connection string you can get from config

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Default"];
```

or you can create a custom repository and get it from DbContext